# Moq Setup returns but doesnt return value if Optional Argument is in interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have an interface that I'm moq-ing out for a IO.

```
internal interface IOWrapper : IDisposable
{
    bool IsConnected { get; }
    Task<int> ReadAsync1(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
    Task<int> ReadAsync2(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)); 
}
```

My test and Moq are setup as follows

```
[Test]
public async Task TestReadAsync()
{
    // Arrange 
    byte[] AutoAck = new byte[] {192, 74, 6, 8, 1, 74, 2, 8, 0, 193};

    Mock<IOWrapper> ioWrapper = new Mock<IOWrapper();
    ioWrapper.SetupGet(x=>x.IsConnected).Returns(true);
    ioWrapper.Setup(x =>
            x.ReadAsync1(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));

     ioWrapper.Setup(x =>
            x.ReadAsync2(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));


    // Act
    bool response = await gtwyDriver.GetAutomaticAck();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response, "Auto Ack Not Set Correctly");

}
```

I have a `GatewayDriver` Class that I"m trying to test it is polling the IO on a long running task.

```
//....
_pollSerialTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(PollSerial, _pollSerialCancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
//....

private async void PollSerial(object o)
{
    while (_omniPort.IsConnected)
    {
        // Read from serial port stream into ring buffer
        try
        {
            _bufferCounter += await _omniPort.ReadAsync1(_buffer, _bufferCounter,_buffer.Length - _bufferCounter);
             _bufferCounter += await _omniPort.ReadAsync2(_buffer, _bufferCounter,_buffer.Length - _bufferCounter);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _logger.Error(exc, $"MobileGrwy {_omniPort.Name} PollSerial Exception ");
            return;
        }
        // Internal logic based on read value from buffer. 
    }
}
```

`ReadAsync1` Returns with the expected value. `ReadAsync2` will return but without a value. Believe this is related to the Optional Cancellation Token on the Interface

I have tried the following different setups for `ReadAsync2`. All seem to demonstrate the same behavior. The `ReadAsync2` will return in the class I am trying to test but it returns no value.

```
x.ReadAsync2(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));
x.ReadAsync2(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
            .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));
x.ReadAsync2(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(),  new CancellationToken()))
            .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));
```

If the lambda for the Moq Setup didn't match I would not expect the `ReadAsync2` to ever return.

Any Idea on why this would return but not return a value

Comment: You need to include a `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()` for `ReadAsync2` setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a `It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()` for `ReadAsync2` setup as optional parameters need to be catered for when mocking the method to be invoked.

```
ioWrapper.Setup(_ => _.ReadAsync2(
                         It.IsAny<byte[]>(), 
                         It.IsAny<int>(), 
                         It.IsAny<int>(), 
                         It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
                     )
                )
        .ReturnsAsync(BitConverter.ToInt32(AutoAck, 0));
```

Comment: I thought i had tried this using  the CancelationToken.None and / or new CancellationToken. but adding the is any worked as well.